# Failed PCI Audit Diffie-Hellman Tomcat 7

Tags: openssl, tomcat7

We failed our periodic PCI audit because our Tomcat 7 is allowing Diffie-Hellman key exchanges. I'm not big on Tomcat and I've done some research to no avail.

The audit said I have 3 choices to correct this.

1. Upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.0. Not available in YUM.
2. Disable FIPS mode. Some say not the best option.
3. Config ciphersuite to not include any Diffie-Hellman key exchanges. Best guess, this is what I need.

What we are running:
Tomcat 7.0.23
OpenSSL 0.9.8e
CentOS 5.5

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is what the audit said:

"Description: SSL Server Accepts Weak Diffie-Hellman Keys Synopsis: The remote
SSL/TLS server accepts a weak Diffie-Hellman public value. Impact: The remote
SSL/TLS server accepts a weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) public key value. This flaw may
aid an attacker in conducting a man-in-the-middle (MiTM) attack against the
remote server since it could enable a forced calculation of a fully predictable
Diffie-Hellman secret. By itself, this flaw is not sufficient to set up a MiTM attack
(hence a risk factor of 'none'), as it would require some SSL implementation flaws
to affect one of the clients connecting to the remote host.

Data Received: It was possible to complete a full SSL handshake by sending a DH key with a value of 1. Other references : OSVDB:70945, OSVDB:71845

Resolution: OpenSSL is affected when compiled in FIPS mode. To resolve this issue, either upgrade to OpenSSL 1.0.0, disable FIPS mode or configure the ciphersuite used by the
server to not include any Diffie-Hellman key exchanges. PolarSSL is affected. To
resolve this issue, upgrade to version 0.99-pre3 / 0.14.2 or higher. If using any
other SSL implementation, configure the ciphersuite used by the server to not
include any Diffie-Hellman key exchanges or contact your vendor for a patch."

Answer (score 0):

Use 3.

You can Google 'disable TLS Tomcat 7' to find how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked after adding a list of allowed ciphers to the Tomcat configuration in conf/server.xml to disable the weak Diffie-Hellman ciphers:

```
    <Connector
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        port="8000"
        ...
        scheme="https"
        secure="true"
        clientAuth="false"
        sslProtocol="TLS" 
        SSLEnabled="true"
        ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA"
        redirectPort="8443"
```